# Error when moving Azure certificate to another subscription: Property id '' at path 'properties.keyVaultId' is invalid

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-appservice, azure-resource-group

I am trying to move my Azure AppService and all inked resources to another subscription through Azure portal. I am doing the following steps:

1. Go to my AppService's resource group
2. Select all resources within this resource group: AppService, AppService Plan, AppService Domain, DNS Zone, SSL Certificate
3. Then click "Move" -> "Move to another subscription"
4. Select target subscription and resource group, and click "Next"
5. Wait for validation to finish, and see the following error linked to the SSL Certificate resource ([screenshot](https://i.snipboard.io/iG6S0w.jpg)):

```
Property id '' at path 'properties.keyVaultId' is invalid
```

I am using Azure's free managed SSL Certificate, and it's not stored in KeyVault.

How do I work around this error?

Comment: It appears this is an open issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/18470  I've tried several methods and I think the only workaround at the moment is to delete-recreate.  My keyVaultId on the existing cert is null, so this must be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run into this situation myself. The free App Service managed certificates on App Services are not supported when moving subscriptions.

More details about this at Microsoft's website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-limitations/app-service-move-limitations#move-with-free-managed-certificates